# How to resize Word shape object with keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, shapes, resizing

I have some shapes that are very small. I can *move* these with the arrow keys, but resizing them does not seem to be possible (eg. with Shift-arrow or Ctrl-arrow).

The [Keyboard shortcuts for working with shapes, text boxes, and WordArt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-working-with-shapes-text-boxes-and-WordArt-8b4743d7-579e-457b-9bf0-e556bd271639#bm4) online help does not mention anything either. (Note: The [Keyboard shortcuts for SmartArt graphics](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-SmartArt-graphics-cb414050-420b-4725-b932-a64a0fb09d3f#__toc340840436) help topic does mention Shift-arrow, but as I wrote, that does not work).

Even if I zoom, as soon as the width of the object becomes so small that the indicated vertical resize handle disappears, I no longer see a way to resize the shape vertically:

[image] [image]

Surely I can keep zooming and using the mouse, but I'm looking for a faster way that also resizes 'per pixel'.

Comment: You can use both handles on the corner to resize vertically too. I am not familiar with a keyboard combination for resizing, and I doubt it exists.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do the same *(resizing using only keyboard by small increments) keeping the aspect ratio ?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Please make that a new question, referring to this one - very few people will see your comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2010 on Windows, [as noted by K V](https://superuser.com/a/870580/400170), shapes can be resized using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(arrow key)</kbd> combinations:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) – Increase shape width
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) – Decrease shape width
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow) – Increase shape height
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (down arrow) – Decrease shape height

These resize operations are 'coarse,' as they resize the shape by several pixels for each keypress.  If a finer resize resolution is needed, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(arrow key)</kbd> instead.

In my hands, all of these resizes operate in a 'centered' fashion for floating shapes: the position of the shape on the page doesn't change as it's resized.

---

To note, this ***does not work*** in Word 2007 for Windows; the behavior instead is that described by OP in his [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/870537/how-to-resize-word-shape-object-with-keyboard#comment1652204_870580) to K V's answer, where the selection just hops over to the main text of the document.  While I don't know of a simple keyboard shortcut for resizing in this situation, a possible workaround is to use the `Size` tools in the `Drawing Tools` Ribbon menu:

[image: Ribbon screencap]

On my system, shapes can be resized in increments of 0.01" via this approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010, I am able to resize using shift arrows.

Holding shift and click on any arrow, that will help in resizing a shape.

Comment: That is strange. I can move them with Ctrl-Arrows, but Shift-Arrow deselects and moves me into text.

Answer (score 1):

Select the image, 
Hold Alt JP, 
Then Alt W (for width) or Alt H (for height), 
Then you can use the arrow keys to increase or decrease the size protortionally, or type in numbers.

Using word 2010 as a visually impaired user.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: What is `Alt JP`?

Comment: I guess `Alt JP` is a hotkey to access "Object tools" menu though these ribbon hotkeys as you press it.

So essentially it's about accessing width/height fields in object menu using alt hotkeys.

I have highlighted the menus on a screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/ota7o86.png (sorry for the Polish version, don't have eng at my hand now, but you should get the point)

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In word 2016 you can´t change proportions by keys anymore you can only increase image size with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and decrease it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>